# Prevent linebreak after </div>

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to prevent a line break after a div with css?

For example I have

```
<div class="label">My Label:</div>
<div class="text">My text</div>
```

and want it to display like:

> My Label: My text

Answer (score 185, accepted):

`display:inline;`

OR

`float:left;`

OR

`display:inline-block;` -- Might not work on all browsers.

What is the purpose of using a `div` here? I'd suggest a `span`, as it is an inline-level element, whereas a `div` is a block-level element.

---

Do note that each option above will work differently.

`display:inline;` will turn the `div` into the equivalent of a `span`. It will be unaffected by `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `height`, etc.

`float:left;` keeps the `div` as a block-level element. It will still take up space as if it were a block, however the width will be fitted to the content (assuming `width:auto;`). It can require a `clear:left;` for certain effects.

`display:inline-block;` is the "best of both worlds" option. The `div` is treated as a block element. It responds to all of the `margin`, `padding`, and `height` rules as expected for a block element. However, it is treated as an inline element for the purpose of placement within other elements.

[Read this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) for more information.

Comment: I used div tags because the were auto generated by a template

Comment: A div with display:inline on it is basically the same as a span.  It's a semantically meaningless container.  The only difference is their default display mode (block vs inline)

Comment: A div with display:inline doesn't work on Safari, it breaks anyway. I'm using span.

Comment: great answer, thank you Jeff. I needed this because an event was not triggered with a span. "display:inline" killed the event too, "float:left" left the event working, but had to strong influence on the rest of the layout, but "display:inline-block" did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 12):

```css
.label, .text {display: inline}
```

Although if you use that, you might as well change the div's to span's.

Answer (score 11):

A DIV is by default a BLOCK display element, meaning it sits on its own line. If you add the CSS property `display:inline` it will behave the way you want. But perhaps you should be considering a SPAN instead?

Answer (score 11):

Try this in CSS for preventing text line breaks in `<div>`:

```css
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Forgot this property. It's helped me

Comment: How does this help? It prevents line-break within a tag. But OP is having two div-tags after each other. And div-tags are per default blocks.

Answer (score 9):

```
<span class="label">My Label:</span>
<span class="text">My text</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `div` elements are block elements, so by default they take upp the full available width.

One way is to turn them into inline elements:

```css
.label, .text { display: inline; }
```

This will have the same effect as using `span` elements instead of `div` elements.

Another way is to float the elements:

```css
.label, .text { float: left; }
```

This will change how the width of the elements is decided, so that thwy will only be as wide as their content. It will also make the elements float beside each other, similar to how images flow beside each other.

You can also consider changing the elements. The `div` element is intended for document divisions, I usually use a `label` and a `span` element for a construct like this:

```html
<label>My Label:</label>
<span>My text</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

div's are used to give structure to a website or to contain a lot of text or elements, but you seem to use them as label, you should use span, it will put both text next to eachother automatically and you won't need to wright css code for it.

And even if other people tell you to float the elements it's best that you just change the tags.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think I've seen this version:

```
<div class="label">My Label:<span class="text">My text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code for normal div
`display: inline;`

use this code if u use it in table 
`display: inline-table;`
better than table

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the `clear:none` css attribute to the label.

```css
.label {
     clear:none;
}
```

Comment: That has no effect, as the `div` still has the default `width:auto` that makes it take up all the available width.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="hassaan">
     <div class="label">My Label:</div>
     <div class="text">My text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#hassaan{ margin:auto; width:960px;}
#hassaan:nth-child(n){ clear:both;}
.label, .text{ width:480px; float:left;}
```

Comment: You may want to explain your answer for the benefit of the OP

Answer (score 0):

try float your div's in css

```css
.label {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}
.text {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Remember to make the next element `clear: left;` to return the document to normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

I have many times succeeded to get div's without line breaks after them, by playing around with the float css attribute and the width css attribute.
Of course after working out the solution you have to test it in all browsers, and in each browser you have to re-size the windows to make sure that it works in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-block;` worked for me.