# How do I prevent a hidden div from creating a linebreak?

Tags: css, html

This question seems to get asked a lot, but I can't find an answer that works for me.

Here is a link to an example (see also HTML below): http://biskup.biowiki.org/blah.html

I want the text to flow after the link, but it doesn't. (I'm looking at this in Firefox & Chrome, on a Mac.)

I'd like to pre-empt some of the common replies I've seen, e.g. here [Prevent linebreak after </div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576605/prevent-linebreak-after-div)

Regarding those answers:

- I can't set the div's display property to "inline" or "inline-block", because I really want it to be hidden. And anyway this doesn't seem to work, for me: see e.g. http://biskup.biowiki.org/blah2.html
- "float:left" doesn't work either
- I can't use a span element, because I really want this to be a div, so I can use it as a popup element
- Since it's a popup element and will eventually be detached/repositioned/reattached by the JavaScript code that pops it up (which will be triggered by clicking on the link right next to the div), I could technically put the div somewhere else in the document (e.g. right at the end); it then wouldn't interrupt the flow; but since this HTML is dynamically generated, it's very convenient to create the div right next to the link that reveals it, as in this example

By the way, I *can* prevent this by adding "display:inline" to the preceding  tag (see example), but that is an extremely awkward workaround

Here's the HTML for my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dumb bug</title>
</head>
<body>


<p/>
<!-- the following (commented-out) line prevents the div from starting a newline; still seeking a better solution that is local to the div or adjacent anchor element -->
<!-- p style="display:inline;"/ -->
Here is some text.
Here is a
<a href="#">  link</a>.
<div style="display:none;">
  This text is inside the hidden div, and should not be shown.
  (A separate piece of code will detach/reattach/position/show this div as a popup, but it's convenient to generate it in the same place as the link.)
</div>
And here is some more text, that I want to flow on the same line after the link.

And some more.

<p/>
<p style="display:inline;"/>
Here is another paragraph.


</body>
</html>
```

Edited to add: the singleton p/ tags are sloppy syntax that most browsers forgive (interpreted as p ... p/ enclosing the div elements), and this was hiding a basic misunderstanding on my part of how the div was inheriting layout style from its parent p.

If I change the singleton p/ tags to this, as suggested by samiz and IsisCode in replies...

```
<p style="display:inline">
...
<p/>
```

...then I get the desired behavior (the text flows).

For the same example with more context on the dynamic behavior (i.e. what happens when the link is clicked).

Comment: try to inculde your `<a href="#">  link</a>.` into your Div it should works probly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the way, I can prevent this by adding "display:inline" to the preceding tag (see example), but that is an extremely awkward workaround

This is how HTML works. `<p>` is a block-line element, that is, it takes up its entire row. Your hidden div isn't causing the line break, the preceding `<p>` element is.

Comment: His code sample is poor. The text and div should all be in the p tag. When this is the case, the line break is still there.

Comment: Thanks samiz. I now realize the code sample is poor because it's outdated. In HTML4 and HTML5 (but not XHTML) you are allowed to use the <p> tag without specifying the closing </p> tag (the closing tag is inferred). All web browsers since (I believe) Mosaic have also allowed the <p> tag in singleton form, i.e. <p/> (the way I've written it), and if I recall, it was common on early webpages. This always struck me as sloppy notation, but somehow it stuck with me, and now I see how it's come back to bite me.

Comment: Thanks IsisCode for the answer, this really helps

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you shouldn't have a `div` inside of a `p` tag. Both are block elements, and it's going to cause the strange behavior you're seeing. Is there a reason why you couldn't use a `span` instead of a `div`?

Comment: Later, when the link is clicked (JS code not shown here), I'm detaching this element from its parentNode and then appending it to document.body, with position:fixed, so it's a popup element. That doesn't seem to work if it's a <span>. Here's a more complete example: http://localhost/~yam/schooz/test.html

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ArsK/3/

Add `float:left` to a div containing your top text.

```
<p/>
<!-- the following (commented-out) line prevents the div from starting a newline; still seeking a better solution that is local to the div or adjacent anchor element -->
<!-- p style="display:inline;"/ -->


<div style="float:left;">
     Here is some text.
     Here is a
     <a href="#">  link</a>.
</div>


<div style="display:none;">
  This text is inside the hidden div, and should not be shown.
  (A separate piece of code will detach/reattach/position/show this div as a popup, but it's convenient to generate it in the same place as the link.)
</div>
And here is some more text, that I want to flow on the same line after the link.

And some more.

<p/>
<p style="display:inline;"/>
Here is another paragraph.​
```