# How to prevent line-breaks between an element and its after-element?

Tags: html, css

I have some definition lists with dynamic content. They are displayed below each other with the `<dt>` and `<dd>` pairs on one line. Each `<dt>` ends with a colon, which is not part of the content. Instead the colon is provided via css after element.

```css
dt:after {
  content: ":";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cat name</dt>
  <dd>Puss</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>dog name</dt>
  <dd>Lassie</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>horse name</dt>
  <dd>Fury</dd>
</dl>
```

If there is not much space, the content of the dl-Elements can and should wrap. But at certain widths only the colon jumps on the next line which I'd like to prevent.

I tried using `white-space: nowrap;` but then there will also be no line break between the two different words in the `<dt>`-element.

I'd prefer a CSS solution, if possible.

Comment: shouldn't the colon be on the dt instead of the dl?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3576628/5051731 might help

Comment: `dt { display:inline-block; white-space:pre; } dt:after { content:":"; }` …?

Comment: @Pete You are totally right, that was a mistake in my question (not the original code) and I edited that.

Comment: @misorude Now the words stay on the same line togehter, but the colon still jumps to the next row. I need the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css selector was targeting the wrong element. It has to point to `dt:after`

```css
dt:after {
  content: ":";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cat name</dt>
  <dd>Puss</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>dog name</dt>
  <dd>Lassie</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>horse name</dt>
  <dd>Fury</dd>
</dl>
```

#### [Edit]

Change the `dt:after` to `display:inline`. When the `DL` width gets too small and the contents drop onto a new line, the colon will stay attached to the last word.

```css
dt:after {
  content: ":";
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>cat name</dt>
  <dd>Puss</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>dog name</dt>
  <dd>Lassie</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>horse name</dt>
  <dd>Fury</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: It was wrong in my question (I edited that), but not in the original code.